# Java update fields in runtime without reflection

Tags: java, class, object, runtime, field

I have this class:

```
@Data
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Boolean isActive;
    ...
    //30 more fields
}
```

And I receive data like `fieldName:newValue` for example:

```
name : "Tom"
isActive: "false"
id : "666"
```

How can I update all fields in runtime?(**without using reflection**)

under question:

I need first validate all the fields before updating. if at least one is not valid, then immediately throw an exception. Validation on all fields is different (by length, by mask, etc.)

Comment: Maybe this is a good usecase for Hibernate Validator (or a JSR349 implementation) http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/

Comment: Anyway, why is the class instantiated before validation? Just instantiate it after validation passed.